# submit form in webbrowser control, get result in winform. how?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have a winform application that i embeded a webrowser control.
I load an html in the webbrowser control, fill the form in the html and click submit
the problem is that i need to be able to capture the submitted data as variables in the winform app. id this possible? please help me

Comment: Erm, why do you need to read values back that you filled in the form yourself?

Comment: am creating a winfom test app for students, because of flexibility, i decided to use html form to collect data from. the html form (which will include questions and html form controls) will be generated automatically based on randomly generated set of questions. do you think i can solve this another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can attach to button click event code:

```
var theButton = webbrowser1.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton")
theButton.Click += (sender, args) => { ... };
```

and in handler you can get form fields from:

```
webbrowser1.Document
```

It allows you to capture filled form actually before it's submited. Ofcource all this stuff must be done in **DocumentCompleted** Event.

Hope it helps.